# Mac OS X: Update Python for Shell

Tags: macos, shell, updates, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Python on Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/225550/using-python-on-mac)

So, I see similar questions, but none of the answers work for me.

I updated Python to 3.1.3 from 2.6.1. Everything works, except: When I type `python` into Terminal, I get:

> Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   >>>

So, how do I change the version of Python that runs in the Shell? I've tried the script that they provide. It adds their directory to my $PATH, but it still doesn't change the version that'd displayed from Terminal. Here's what I get when I `echo $PATH`:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

It appears that the script provided has added their directory for every time I ran the script (I tried it a few times, naturally).

Here's some caps of what is in the other relevant folders it mentions:

**/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin**

[image]

**/usr/local/bin**

[image]

**/usr/bin**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just type `python3`. You might need to change your `$PATH` by editing `~/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

They did this for compatibility reasons, Python 3 breaks things.

---

You could define a shell function or alias to map `python` to `python3`, this way old scripts would continue to run, and you can type `python` and get version 3.

Add to `.bash_profile`:

```
alias python='python3'
```

`/usr/bin/env python` continues to provide Python 2.

Comment: When I type `python3`, I get `-bash: python3: command not found`. Ideas?

Comment: @Nathan See my edited post.

Comment: Will that just add another link to the framework? I've got three or for already...

Comment: @Nathan What do you mean by "link"? If the Python 3 bin directory is already on your path, `python3` would have launched Python 3 instead of showing an error. The path simply defines which directories are searched for a program when you type its name. Since the `python3` binary resides in the directory from my post, that directory needs to be added to the path. No file system changes or "links" added.